# How do i get a program to loop until a character is entered?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, char

What I'm exactly trying to achieve is: You enter your name, get a response like 'your name is', and if you enter a number you get a response like 'invalid input' which loops you back to the 'Enter your name' part

```
#include <stdio.h>
char i[20];
int result;
int main()

{
void findi(); // im trying to loop it back here if a number is entered instead of a character
printf("Enter your name\n");
result = scanf("%s", &i);
while(getchar() != '\n'){ //dont know how to make it work without the '!'
    if(result = '%s'){
        printf("Your name is: %s", &i); 
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid input"); //doesnt work 
        findi();
    }
   }
}
//program just ends after a character is entered instead of continuing
```

Comment: `while(getchar() != '\n')` can be written as `while(getchar() - '\n')` if you want to avoid `!` for some reason.

Comment: `result = '%s' ` definitelly wrong

Answer (score 0):

- Using `&i` (`char(*)[20]`) for `%s` (expects `char*`) invokes *undefined behavior*.
- The condition `result = '%s'` (assign implementation-defined value to `result` without checking its value) looks weird.
- Calling `findi()` (not disclosed here) from `main()` need not mean a loop.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char i[20];
    printf("Enter your name\n");
    /* an infinite loop (loop until return or break) */
    for (;;) {
        int number_exists = 0, j;
        /* limit length to read and check the result*/
        if (scanf("%19s", i) != 1) {
            printf("read error\n");
            return 1;
        }
        /* check if a number is entered */
        for(j = 0; i[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)i[j])) {
                number_exists = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        /* see the result */
        if (number_exists) {
            /* one or more number is entered */
            printf("Invalid input\n");
        } else {
            /* no number is entered : exit from the loop */
            printf("Your name is: %s\n", i); 
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ive learned a lot from this